# About Disjoint union of a set and partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

As Wikipedia defines partition as"A partition of a set X is a set of non-empty subsets of X such that every element x in X is in exactly one of these subsets(i.e., X is a disjoint union of the subsets)" so for this definition let's take an example as follows:.

Let X={1,2} and let A={(1,1),(2,2),(1,3)} where (1,1)$\in $ A1, (2,2)$\in $ A2 and (1,3)$\in$A3 such that A1, A2, A3 are index subset of A. Here the 1 in (1,1) is different than 1 in (1,3).

Now my question is 'A' a partition of X? Is X a disjoint union of these subsets?

Comment: $X$ has only two elements in it.  The only two possible partitions of $X$ are $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\}\}$.  There are no others.  I don't know what you are trying to do with your "index subsets" but I suspect you have the wrong idea (*and probably the wrong notation as well*).

Comment: What about the disjoint union? Can X be disjoint union of sets in 'A'?

Comment: $(1,1)$ is not an element of $X$.  There is a difference between the element $1$ and the ordered pair $(1,1)$.  These are not the same objects.  No, $X$ is not equal to the union of elements of $A$.

Comment: Your $A_i$s form a partition of $A$, not $X$. The disjoint union is not a partition of a single set. The disjoint union is used when we take the union of two sets and we want to remember the origin of common elements.

Comment: I think you have a confusion about "disjoint union". Disjoint union can mean one of 2. Given $A,B$ a set, then it can be what you thought about: $A\times\{0\}∪B\times\{1\}$ (with the natural generalization for more sets). But if $A\cap B=∅$ the disjoint union can also just be $A\cup B$, the definition meant the second variation. Given $X$, a set $Y$ is a partition of $X$ if for $a≠b∈Y$ we have $a\cap b=∅$ (disjoint) and $\bigcup Y=X$ (union)